# bash echo string >> file does not work

Tags: bash, echo, io-redirection

I wrote the following script:

```
for filename in `find . -name '*'.cpp | grep $IN_REGEX | grep -v $OUT_REGEX`
do
    echo "Output file is $OUTPUT_FILE"
    count=`git log --pretty=format: --name-only $filename | grep -v ^$ | wc -l`
    echo "$count    $filename" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
done
```

But nothing gets written into the output file.

Please note:

1. I have set the values for OUTPUT_FILE, IN_REGEX and OUT_REGEX.
2. The code inside the loop is being executed. I checked this with an sh -x invokation.
3. When I remove the >> $OUTPUT_FILE I get the output.
4. I tried a touch $OUTPUT_FILE inside the script and that is working fine.

Can someone please point out what is my mistake here?

Comment: What are IN_REGEX and OUT_REGEX?  What does `for filename in find . -name '*'.cpp` print?

Comment: They are regex to limit the list of files.

Comment: Are you absolutely shure you are running `bash`? This is a feature in `zsh` and some other shells, but not `bash`.

Comment: Yes. It is bash. I have a sha-bang too. Also, can you please tell me which feature you are talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about `set -C`. In `bash` it will only disallow `>` if the file exists. In `zsh` it will also disallow `>>` if the file does not exist.

Comment: Check if your version of `find` supports the `-regex` primary; you could use that in place of both the calls to `grep`. Also, the `-c` flag of `grep` eliminates the need to call `wc -l`.

Comment: Instead of appending to `$OUTFILE` inside the loop, you can put a single `> $OUTFILE` *outside* the loop to collect the cumulative standard output.

Comment: n.m., bash and zsh seem to have different inode entries and sizes. So, I don't think that I am using zsh instead.

Comment: chepner, yes. I tried what you suggest, but it is still not working. For some reason, redirection to a file does not seem to work.

Comment: I tried redirecting the output to a different directory and it is working fine. Seems to be something about this directory? Here are the permissions on this directory: `drwxr-xr-x` Doesn't seem wrong to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
for filename in `find . -name '*'.cpp
```

is a [image]

(break on space in file names)

You should instead do :

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo "Output file is $OUTPUT_FILE"
    count=$(git log --pretty=format: --name-only "$file" | grep -v '^$' | wc -l)
    echo "$count    $file" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"      
done < <(find . -name '*.cpp' | grep "$IN_REGEX" | grep -v "$OUT_REGEX")
```

For this to work, ensure that `$OUTPUT_FILE` have a path in it.

Comment: I take your point. But I know that there are no spaces in any of the file names.

Comment: ./gitlog.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./gitlog.sh: line 28: `done < <(find . -name '*.cpp' | grep "$IN_REGEX" | grep -v "$OUT_REGEX")

Comment: use `bash` for real, not `sh` =)

Comment: @sputnick: or write code that is not unnecessarily `bash`-specific.

Comment: In my machine, bash and sh are the same hard link.

Comment: sputnick, do you know what "unnecessarily" means?